# How to say "in front of everyone" in Chinese

Tags: translation

I have 在大家面前 and 在公共场所。It is for the sentence "I don't want to say this in front of everyone."

Comment: 在大家面前 confirmed by iciba 翻译， 相关例句：1.They used to kiss and cuddle in front of everyone.他们过去经常在人前搂抱亲吻。 iciba has ２ more  sample sentences

Comment: Vote for `在大家面前`.

Answer (score 2):

formal one: 众目睽睽之下
normal one: 在大家面前 / 在大家都在的时候 (If you know the guys around you, else: ) 在这么多人面前 / 在这么多人在的时候

The sentence: 我不想在大家都在的时候说这种话(If you know the guys around you, else: ) 我不想在这么多人面前说这种话

Answer (score 0):

公開 is probably the shortest way to capture what you want to say.

我不想公開講這些話。

I don't want to say this in public/ in front of everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to say this in front of everyone
= 我不想在大家面前说这个